# jQuery ajax update value immediately using keyup()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a small jQuery function which I am using to capture the input of a text field as zipcode and then grab some relevant data from the db (snow fall and wind speed).

The function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var zip = $('#id_zipcode');
    zip.change(function() {
      function updateEvnFactors(){
        var selected = zip.val();
        if (selected) {
            $.getJSON(get_zip_factors_url, {zipcode: selected}, function(env_data, jqXHR){
                $('#snow_fall').html(env_data[0].snow);
                $('#wind_speed').html(env_data[0].wind);
            });
        }
      }
      updateEvnFactors();
      $('#id_zipcode').keyup(updateEvnFactors);
   });
});
```

Where the element `#id_zipcode` is a text input. This works in a rudimentary way, but the html elements `#snow_fall` and `#wind_speed` are only updated when the user tabs onto another form field or clicks somewhere outside of the `#zip_code` input.

What am I missing to make the html elements update as soon as there are valid values returned from the ajax call (i.e. a valid zipcode passed).

As a bonus question - how can I limit my ajax to only being activated when there are >=5 digits in the input field?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to use inner scope function from outer scope function. it's impossible as I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a bonus question - how can I limit my ajax to only being activated when there are >=5 digits in the input field?

```
if (selected.length >= 5)
```

Now regarding the main question, you subscribed for the `onchange` event, it fires only on a change + blur(lose focus). this is what the spec says.

You can change to:

```
$('#id_zipcode').keyup(function() {
    var selected = this.value;
    if (selected.length >= 5) {
        $.getJSON(get_zip_factors_url, {
            zipcode: selected
        }, function(env_data, jqXHR) {
            $('#snow_fall').html(env_data[0].snow);
            $('#wind_speed').html(env_data[0].wind);
        });
    }
}).keyup();​
```

Comment: arggh. Yep `ip.keyup(function() {` is different to `zip.change() {`. Must have been left over when I was experimenting with `.change()`

Comment: @DarwinTech. I cleaned your code completely, this is now a lot better, take look.

Comment: With your code I get an unexpected illegal token error. Some typo?

Comment: @DarwinTech. Not in my code. Maybe you pasted it wrong, or perhaps it collide with something else you're using.

Comment: Ok. Yes, i think there was a problem with another jQuery function. However, the code you posted does not work for me.

Comment: ok - yep. Need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){}`. Is it better practice to have all my jQuery functions in the same script or separate. I had seperate scripts all using the `$(document).ready()` function, which is where the conflict was I believe.

Comment: @DarwinTech. It's not that important, but I put them all inside one `ready` call.

Comment: As an extension - is there an easy way to register deletion of characters from the input field so that the values do not persist when the user hits delete or retypes? `.keydown()` perhaps?

Comment: @DarwinTech. I'm not sure I understood the question.

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296180/jquery-ajax-call-updates-on-character-deletion

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `onchange` event only fires once the field has lost focus. I think your code should look more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_zipcode').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 5) {
            $.getJSON(get_zip_factors_url, {zipcode: selected}, function(env_data, jqXHR) {
                $('#snow_fall').html(env_data[0].snow);
                $('#wind_speed').html(env_data[0].wind);
            });
        }
    });
});
```