# JQuery ajax call updates on character deletion

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a small jQuery function which collects data from the server depending on a zipcode input field:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_zipcode').keyup(function() {
    var selected = this.value;
    if (selected.length > 3) {
        $.getJSON(get_zip_factors_url, {
            zipcode: selected
        }, function(env_data, jqXHR) {
            $('#snow_fall').html(env_data[0].snow);
            $('#wind_speed').html(env_data[0].wind);
        });
    }
  }).keyup();
});
```

This works fine now. However, if the user deletes characters the values rendered for `#snow_fall` and `#wind_speed` persist. Is there some way I can register this deletion and revert the values to say a 'not available' string when the user deletes characters which result in no valid data being returned from the server?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking for zip code values why not change to if(selected.length == 5) and then use the else of the if statement to set snow_fall and wind_speed to "not available"?

Comment: Ha. That does the trick. I was looking for another event handler but a simple else statement does the trick! If you care to post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for zip code values why not change to if(selected.length == 5) and then use the else of the if statement to set snow_fall and wind_speed to "not available"?

Answer (score 1):

I might just modify the response as such:

```
$.getJSON(get_zip_factors_url, {
            zipcode: selected
        }, function(env_data, jqXHR) {
            if(env_data[0].valid == true )
            {
                $('#snow_fall').html(env_data[0].snow);
                $('#wind_speed').html(env_data[0].wind);
            } else {
                $('#snow_fall').html('Not Available');
                $('#wind_speed').html('Not Available');
            }
        });
```

Alternatively, you could just keep track of the zip entered or the length globally and just check that without having to go through the trouble of making an ajax call.